# How can i retrieve instrumentation key for an Application Insight (which resides in another resource group) in ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Is there any way to retrieve the Instrumentation Key for an Application Insights (which resides in another resource group) in an ARM template ?

I have already created an appInsights using ARM template using the below code,

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "AppInsightsName": { "type": "string" },
    "Location": { "type": "string", "defaultValue": "westeurope" }
  },
  "variables": {
    //"apiVersion": "2018-02-01-preview",
    "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
    "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
    "ApplicationInsightsName": "[parameters('AppInsightsName')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "name": "[variables('ApplicationInsightsName')]",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "kind": "other",
      "properties": {
        "applicationId": "[variables('ApplicationInsightsName')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now i am trying to link azure function app which runs in another resource group with this appInsights.

Below is the code i have tried,

```
{
  "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
  "value": "[reference(resourceId(variables('AppInsightsResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('ApplicationInsightsName'))).InstrumentationKey]"
}
```

But i am getting the below error,

[image]

Can someone give some idea how to crack this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You **can** use the reference function for resources that are already deployed from another template.  You just need to pass in the apiVersion parameter as indicated in the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#reference.  Note that you also need to change the property that you are referencing from '.InstrumentationKey' to '.properties.InstrumentationKey'.

```
"value": "[reference(resourceId(variables('AppInsightsResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('ApplicationInsightsName')), '2015-05-01', 'Full').properties.InstrumentationKey]"
```

You can deploy the following template to validate (just replace the two variables with your values):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
  },
  "variables": {
      "AppInsightsResourceGroup": "myAIRG",
      "ApplicationInsightsName": "myAI"
  },
  "resources": [
  ],
  "outputs": {
      "appInsightsKey": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "[reference(resourceId(variables('AppInsightsResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('ApplicationInsightsName')), '2015-05-01', 'Full').properties.InstrumentationKey]"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great. One note, when not using 'Full', you don't need to add the .properties part